# Question about the switching behavior of a transistor as a switch

Tags: transistors, oscilloscope, switching

I was doing some testing and my intent was to run a transistor as a switch. I was providing an input square wave from a source, and was looking at the fall time characteristics.

Basically this is the circuit I was using to operate it, with the square wave being provided to the base through the resistor.

[image]

However while observing the fall time characteristics i.e when the square wave is turning off. I was getting a signal plotted on the scope below.

[image]

Basically the green signal is the plot for Vce and the yellow one(falling) is Vbe. Now I would expect to see Vce rise after Vbe falls down, but I was observing it rising a little before Vbe and there is a small kink where the left cursor is, where it gets triggered. Can someone suggest reasons to why it would cause the Vce trigger to soon when its higher than the base voltage to keep it ON ? Thank you for looking.

Comment: Insufficient measurement accuracy on Vbe resolution to see the threshold for Vbe vs Ib switches the output. Try 5 divisions for Vbe and reduce your ground noise on both signals with shorter leads. At present your noise is almost 10% of your Vbe signal. Otherwise the circuit capacitance and current limit affects slew rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A run through SPICE shows that the delay is real. Delay depends upon the transistor characteristics. The transistor does turn off well after the base voltage drops quickly to zero. In your circuit, the collector current would be of interest, since LED brightness is directly proportional to current flowing through. A plot of collector current does show that collector current falls toward zero about 0.6 uS after Vin drops to zero, in the SPICE simulation:
[image]

Notice the small step in base voltage at the 1.0 uS mark, when the transistor is told to turn off (just like your measurement). At this same moment, collector current pulses up above the 12 mA mark, because of base-to-collector capacitance. This short pulse is difficult to see in the blue plot of Ic.
MOSfet switches don't have this storage delay, but their very large capacitances must be charged and discharged - requiring large pulse currents.

Comment: Thanks for running the simulation. While it is true, why should we be seeing that small drop at 1us in Vbase ? And looks like I might be getting my basics wrong, but doesn't a transistor stop conducting once the Vbase goes below 0.6V(assuming datasheet says 0.6)  ? So how does that small drop make a difference ?

Comment: This transistor is heavily saturated when Vin turns it off. At the "step" no more base current comes from Vin, but excess charge within the transistor must move out of the base region. Those minority carriers are sluggish. The transistor slowly comes out of saturation, until @ 1.6 uS it enters its linear active region (out of saturation) and then switches off quite quickly. Schottky diodes can be used to avoid heavily saturated transistor switches. Or speed-up capacitor parallel with base resistor works too.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely need to brush up my basics again. Just to confirm, by Vin you mean the 5V supply which powers the LED correct ?

Comment: Please excuse my ambiguity...Vin (in green) is the signal source that drives the 1K base resistor. In my simulation, it switched very quickly from +5v to 0v, one microsecond after the simulation started. The LED anode was connected to steady +5v DC during the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is your base drive. Assuming that your yellow is actually Vbe (and not the input to the 1k resistor), two things become apparent. First, Vbe is not being measured accurately, since your trace seems to indicate about a 1 volt swing, instead of about 0.7 volts. Second, you'll notice that Vbe starts falling at the cursor, just at the same time Vce starts rising. If you go back to basic theory, you'll find that the current through the base is exponential with respect to the voltage, so that "gentle" drop in voltage is actually producing a rather large drop in base current. As a result, Vce is rising.

I suggest that, instead of looking at Vbe, you monitor the input to the 1k resistor. I'm pretty sure you'll find that it drops over a period of more than a microsecond, and probably pretty linearly. As it does, the base current will drop about the same amount, although this won't have a big effect until the drive voltage gets down around a volt or two. But it does have an effect which you can see.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Couple of clarifications, 1. What swing are you referring to ?     2. From what I understood, isn't it the voltage responsible for switching the transistor and current in FET's  ? Where does the current come into play here?  3. In your 2nd paragraph, are you saying that the input to the 1k resistor would be dropping over a much wider range ?

Comment: Vbe. The yellow trace.

Comment: Sorry, just going to add one final comment based on what I understand. So I understand it should be 0.7, and we are seeing something along the lines of 1V. Apart from that, before I look at the current-voltage relation(which I haven't in a long time), isn't a transistor switched using the voltage and not the current unlike a FET ? So why would we be concerned with the current here ?

Comment: Comment 2(for reference) :   Also, I believe this is the behavior we observe: http://i.imgur.com/s8CLUtj.jpg and we see that with a small change of Vbe, the Ib changes significantly. Are you suggesting, that due to the small kink at the first cursor, our Ib goes to 0 then(similar to the picture in this comment), and that causes Vce to be triggered ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things floated through my mind when reading your question. (I upped you because you took the trouble to actually look at things and come up with such a question -- too rare here, I think.) One of them was charge storage in the BJT bulk and transit times. Another was to wonder how you'd set things up for measurement. Another was that you should check out your observations by also seeing if a spice simulator *also* would show the effect.

But as all these flew by, another much more obvious one arrived that probably explains the hogs share of what you are seeing and stopped me from wasting time on the rest. It's that a mere \$60\:\textrm{mV}\$ change in the base-emitter voltage would lead to a 10 fold change in the collector current.

Think about that for a moment. Say the LED current is \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$ at 100%. To go from 100% to 90%, the base voltage would change by perhaps \$2.5\:\textrm{mV}\$. With \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ per division, and noise, there's no way you'd see that. To go from 90% to 9% (nearly OFF), the voltage would drop by another \$60\:\textrm{mV}\$. Merely 6% of one division on your scope. And the LED is nearly OFF and therefore the \$V_{CE}\$ has risen to nearly it's maximum value now.

Of course the display would look like that. And I don't need to invoke charge storage and transit times, worry about your wiring or your hookups, or anything else. It's the expected behavior without such complications. Those complications may be there, too. But they aren't needed to explain your observation. I'm sure spice will confirm this.

---

You didn't set things up on the scope well enough to drill in deeper. The explanation above is enough to explain things at your current resolution. But, if you set things up to provide better precision (time and voltage) to narrow in further, it will turn out that my explanation above is no longer enough and you may be able to start pointing to further details which remain unexplained by this single principle alone.

Of course.

At that point, you are starting to dig into why BJT models are in fact more detailed and more complex and why there are so many added terms.

But at the level your display currently shows? That one basic principle is sufficient.

Comment: Good on ya. On my SPICE run, the base voltage dropped 56 mV. at the step. At that point, there's still so much charge shuffling out of the base (multiplied by Beta) that Ic hardly budges. Then, for the next 0.55 uS, base voltage fell slowly for another 25 mV until it finally started to seriously turn off and fell from 0.7v toward zero.